# How to create a 10x10 grid in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, imagebutton

I am creating a small Battleship game and for the Android UI I was hoping to create a 10x10 grid of image buttons or something (anything easy). 
I was following the tutorial provided at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

My problem is that I can't get the images to display in a proper 10x10 format. Using the GridView, I set the num_columns to "10" in the XML but there is no such attribute for the number of rows. 
As phone sizes differ, is there a way to have a 10x10 grid auto fit any screen?

By following the steps in the above link I can display 100 clickable images but my problem is with the formatting. Here's a screenshot of said result:
[image]

I've tried changing values in XML to scale the images down but cannot figure out how to. Apologies for lack of code snippets but I really haven't altered much from the sample given in the above link other than the vertical and horizontal spacing.

Would appreciate any enlightenment, even if it's just to say I am I going about this the wrong way completely.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with a table layout : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/

GridViews, just as ListViews have been designed to contain any number of rows.

But I really doubt you want to use views in your game and not only use a canvas, draw anything and detect clicks without relying on views built-in mechanisms. It's more work but you end with something that will make you much more free to do what you want (for instance not having to deal with the number of rows of a container...)

Answer (score 1):

go to this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) and try 2nd example Custom Adapter example.
just change android:numColumns="auto_fit" to android:numColumns="10".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do what you want with a `GridLayout`, but not with a `GridView` (which automatically scrolls vertically). Using a `GridLayout`, set all the buttons to have 0dp layout width and height, and set their layout gravity to `fill`.